# JNLP Desktop.browse doesn't work when application ran from server. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, hyperlink, jnlp, java-web-start

**Scenerio:** I have a jframe on on java webstart application that has html (clickable)link. When I run the application as a java application from eclipse it works. But when I launch it from a jboss/tomcat server the link fails to work.

**Additional Information**

project is **Signed** and Security settings are set to **all permissions**

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is an exception thrown when you try clicking it?

Comment: @Vulcan no exceptions are being thrown and the boolean returning for `isSupported` returns true in both cases

Comment: What is your [`<security>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/development.html#security) setting?

Comment: @trashgod it is <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>

Comment: Is it [signed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)?

Comment: @trashgod yes its signed

Comment: Please edit your question to include these facts; an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem would also help.

Comment: Besides an SSCCE, also post the content of the JNLP - after checking it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) (and correcting any errors).